# Handsontable: ReadOnly-Cells not working

Tags: handsontable, readonly-attribute

I am so new to HOT, I've not even started using it! I'm just trying to go through the examples to see if I might be able to use it as a grid-control in my app. But when I look at examples like [this one](http://docs.handsontable.com/0.20.2/demo-read-only.html), it doesn't behave as readonly: I am able to overwrite every cell in the "Nissan"-Example as well as selecting the whole table and press `<Del>`.

Does the "readonly" only imply that no data will be changed in the returned object or is me being able to edit everything considered a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking support, it turned out this was unintended behaviour and will be fixed. Problem was only in the way the demo was coded - it was not adjusted to latest changes in HOT.